# Adding column lines to css grid system

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I would like to show some of grid columns as line. I have tried to make it with grid gap, but in this way the position of the elements in the div changes.

In Css

```css
.MyTable{
  width:auto;
  height:1000px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(365, 1fr);
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

In Html

```html
<div class="MyTable"></div>
```

For example: I would like to see column lines for every 7th index of grid even if there is no item inside of div element.

[Example apperance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOXhx.jpg)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want every seventh element to be ofset?

Comment: I dont know what do you mean with ofset, but I would like to see some of grid lines. Yes, I want column line for every seventh element for most of them. Two line of them I will set manuel.

Comment: column numbers 365(grid-template-column). It represent number of days in a year. I would like to see lines for weeks.

Comment: It might be `365 / 7` columns and you can still use grid inside each but I think it should be another approach if you want to display a calendar, every 7 days are one block but it is not guaranteed that the first day of the year is Monday.

Comment: I am try to implement not a calender but it is near to it. It does not important to be able to guarantee that first day of year is monday. @dqlgnoleht

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe help you

```css
.MyTable {
  width: auto;
  height: 1000px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(365, 1fr);
  counter-reset: counter -1;
  margin-top: 1.5em;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 1em;
  counter-increment: counter;
}

.MyTable div:nth-child(7n) {
  border-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

.MyTable div:nth-child(7n)::before {
  content: counter(counter);
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.4em;
}
```

```html
<div class="MyTable">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but it is not what I want to see. You have set color of some of items. I want to see this grid lines to be located above the div elemens. I have tried to make it with z-index and position:absolute. I does not work like how I want.

Comment: Thank you but; there sould be a easier solution. To be able to show every 7th element, I sould not have to put 365 times div elements. Does it possible to make without div elements? Directly in css I mean.

Comment: @NiceCodeBro, css can only style elements that are already in html. as a last resort, you can use 52 div elements.

Comment: Then I have to specify them with grid-column-start?

Comment: No, you can simulate the position of these elements in a shared container so that it appears that the internal elements are 365, not 52.

Comment: It sounds good. I did not try it but I believe it will works. Thank you for your support.